Javac - How to treat all warnings as errors except deprecations?
I am using the -Werror flag with javac to have all warnings be treated as errors (Related to this post: Make javac treat warnings as errors).
However, I am trying to exclude deprecations from that rule, such that deprecations still get treated as warnings and not as errors.  Is there a way to do this with another compiler flag?
